# Ubuntu Disk crashes when I try to encrypt 2TB HDD Seagate

Tags: hard-drive, disk

I want to encrypt entire HDD with LUKS+Ext4, but after I hit Format - Disk crashes. Can I do this in terminal somehow? Or what is the problem? Thanks!

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and

gnome-disk-utility 3.18.3.1
UDisks 2.1.7 (built against 2.1.6)